# Creating ND arrays at runtime with standard library

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have three arrays

```
a = [2]
b = [2,3,6]
c = [1]
```

I want to merge them such that I get an array of size `len(a)*len(b)` containing all permutations of both. (C will always contain a single value)

I thought that something like this would work

```
newArr = [for i in range len(a)*len(b) [for x in a][for y in b][for z in c]]
print(newArr)

[[2,2,1],[2,3,1],[2,6,1]]
```

However it doesn't seem to allow it within the syntax of the language. Does anyone have any clue as to how I do this with standard libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[x, y, z] for x in a for y in b for z in c]
```

For example:

```
>>> [[x, y, z] for x in [2] for y in [2,3,6] for z in [1]]
[[2, 2, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 6, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [itertools.product(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools

a = [2]
b = [2,3,6]
c = [1]

p = itertools.product(a, b, c)

print(list(p))

[(2, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1), (2, 6, 1)]
```